# PhoneGap: Bring the WebView to the focus after completing UI PLugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to get back the control to the WebView after my video Plugin ends playing the video.

The VideoView plays a video in a UIThread. After the video is complete the thread should end and the main WebView should be set on focus and Active.

How Can I do that?

```
public class VideoPlayer extends CordovaPlugin {

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {


    if ("playVideo".equals(action)) {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {                         
                final VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                cordova.getActivity().setContentView(videoHolder);
                videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Android/data/Bis/v2.mp4"));
                videoHolder.requestFocus();
                videoHolder.start();            
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.

                videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    // return Control back to the WebView

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could fire an JS event that will trigger some action in the WebView or load another page - What do you need the page to do ?

Comment: Can I close this UI thread and go back to the main WebView?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ?